# How to remove Black Color in ios during the Screen Navigation?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uiviewanimationtransition

As per the image, I am using `navigationController` with my application.

During the Transition from one screen to other screen, a black color is showing.

My `RootViewController` doesn't have the `navigationBar` (it is hidden) whereas the other screens have the Navigation Bar.

Can anyone help? (as I am new in this forum they will not allow me to attach the images.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assign the same navigation bar properties of the destination controller in root controller's viewDidDisappear . setNavigationBarHidden as No.